# Get users location in ons.ready not working

Tags: html, cordova, geolocation, onsen-ui

I have the following code:

```
ons.ready( function() {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function( position ) {
            geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
            geo.lon = position.coords.longitude;
        }
    );
} );
```

Sometimes, but not all the time I get the following error:

```
Location access is not available.
Error in Error callbackId: Geolocation54410059
```

I need the user's location to load data into the main page of my app. Where is the best place to do this?

Answer (score 0):

ons.ready fire when the dom is loaded, you are using a cordova plugin in order to get geolocation position. So you can't use it before cordova is ready.

Just do:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
     // now cordova is ready
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function( position ) {
            geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
            geo.lon = position.coords.longitude;
    });
}, false);
```

And it will be fine I think.

Edit :

Try adding those options to your function :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function( position ) {
                geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                geo.lon = position.coords.longitude;
        }, { maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

you can put whatever value you want for 'enableHighAccuracy' and 'maximumAge' but you must provide a 'timeout' option because there is some quirks in android:

> Android Quirks
>
> If Geolocation service is turned off the onError callback is invoked
>   after timeout interval (if specified). If timeout parameter is not
>   specified then no callback is called.